# Validity of Visa Electron abroad

Tags: eur-euro, european-union, visa, atm, france

I have a Visa Electron card: debit, non-embossed, French, being a "REALYS" and "CB" as well.

I would like to ask what is the validity of such card abroad in cash machines (namely in the Czech Republic). I managed to pay with it online on amazon.DE and sncb.BE.

I'd like to use it to transfer money from France to the Czech Republic by getting them as CZK in a Czech cash machine and writing them cash in my Czech bank account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ATMs you should check if the ATM you're going to use accepts the network you're in. If the ATM has the same logo (it should probably have a whole bunch of logos) that is on your card - it should work. I have not encountered an ATM that wouldn't accept a VISA card in Europe, and I travel a lot.

Comment: So French Visa Electron should be usable in Czech ATM as long as it wears the Visa Electron logo?

Comment: I would expect it to, yes

Comment: This seems to be correct. However, I found out that I can use the card at shops too, each payment costs a EUR 1 fee, but the exchange rate seems to be very good (really close to the official one). So I can use the card for large payments (which I'll likely do anyways). Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @yo' you can answer your own question with this discovery

Answer (score 2):

Visa Electron should be usable in any ATM (and shop) that accepts Visa, especially if the ATM also contains the "Plus" logo.

However, if it's (for example) the card issued by [La Banque Postale](https://www.labanquepostale.fr/particuliers/au_quotidien/moyens_de_paiements/cartes_de_paiement/La_Carte_Realys.Mode_emploi.html) (in French) there are quite low withdrawal and spending limits.  These limits are over a period of the most recent seven days, so it can take a while before you can withdraw more.  So maybe not suitable to transfer a significant amount to your CZK account.

As an alternative to finding an ATM that might have a fee, you can maybe use it to buy something small, then get cashback from stores that offer that.

As it's a debit card, it needs to check the balance in real-time, so there [are reports](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/columnists/gillcharlton/8374121/Travel-advice-using-Electron-cards-abroad.html) of it being often declined if it can't get a fast response from the home bank. In other words, make sure you have an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of paying in shops, there seem to be a very good exchange rate, and the fee in the French bank is EUR 1, which is doable if I use it only for large amounts.